# HTML class names: Should I repeat a prefix on child elements of my widget?

Tags: html, css

My framework will include a chat widget that users can automatically insert into the page. The widget has a tree structure like this:

```
ChatBox
    MessageList
        Message
            Author
            Text
```

I put HTML class and id attributes on the widget's elements, so that users will be able to style them with CSS and manipulate with JS. For example, someone might want to put author names in italics, etc.

These attributes are prefixed with `acme-chat-` (in this example, my framework is called "acme"), to avoid clashes. My question is: **should I use this prefix on every child element of the chat box? Or just the root level element?**

Option A:

```html
<div class="acme-chat" id="acme-chat-314159">
    <div class="acme-chat-messages">
        <div class="acme-chat-message">
            <span class="acme-chat-nickname">Player 1 (Me)</span>
            <span class="acme-chat-message-body">aoeu</span></div>
        <div class="acme-chat-message"><span class="acme-chat-nickname">Player 1 (Me)</span><span
                class="acme-chat-message-body">aoeu</span></div>
        <div class="acme-chat-message"><span class="acme-chat-nickname">Player 1 (Me)</span><span
                class="acme-chat-message-body">aeue</span></div>
        <div class="acme-chat-message"><span class="acme-chat-nickname">Player 2</span><span
                class="acme-chat-message-body">aoeu</span></div>
    </div>
    <input size="40">
    <button type="button">Send</button>
</div>
```

Option B:

```html
<div class="acme-chat" id="acme-chat-2-prisoner-2">
    <div class="messages">
        <div class="message">
            <span class="nickname">Player 1 (Me)</span>
            <span class="message-body">aoeu</span></div>
        <div class="message"><span class="nickname">Player 1 (Me)</span><span
                class="message-body">aoeu</span></div>
        <div class="message"><span class="nickname">Player 1 (Me)</span><span
                class="message-body">aeue</span></div>
        <div class="message"><span class="nickname">Player 2</span><span
                class="message-body">aoeu</span></div>
    </div>
    <input size="40">
    <button type="button">Send</button>
</div>
```

Comment: It depends on the CSS rules to which your HTML will be exposed.

Comment: I think it's good practice to have a namespace prefix to selectors for your components.